# Django = display image on html from views with for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to display image from db with views and in the inspact broswer i see it find my image but still return me 404 error. my models.py:

```
class HomePhoto(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='home_page_images/')
```

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    data = HomePhoto.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'data':data,})
```

html:

```
 {% for d in data %}
    <img src="{{d.img}}" alt="Third slide">
 {% endfor %}
```

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the html in the broswer inspact:

```
<img src="home_page_images/orangeshirt_1ZrO8ay.jpg" alt="Third slide"> <!--THIS IS THE RIGHT PATH AND THE RIGHT NAME OF THE IMAGE-->
```

Comment: Have you tried visiting the image URL? Try adding a `/` at the start of your image URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {% for d in data %}
    <img src="{{d.img.url}}" alt="Third slide">
 {% endfor %}
```

you need to add url: `d.img.url`

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting about accessing the url member:

```
{% for d in data %}
    <img src="{{d.img.url}}" alt="Third slide">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```